# Significato di "la pignatta con due legni verdi non bolle"

Tags: meaning, regional, proverbs

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> *Mio padre alzando la voce.* Io non do mia figlia a un affamato. **La pignatta con due legni verdi non bolle**. Vattene piuttosto in America. Il Signore potrà aiutarti e potrai farti una casa laggiù.

La mia domanda è sulla frase "la pignatta con due legni verdi non bolle" che appare in questo testo. Non ho trovato nessun riferimento su Internet. Si tratta di qualche proverbio? Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pignatta è una pentola, che non si può fare bollire se si usano legni verdi per il fuoco che non si accendono.

In Liguria con significato simile un [proverbio](https://www.pensieriparole.it/proverbi/liguria/proverbio-79372) dice:

> A bellessa a nö fa boggî a pûgnatta (o pignatta)
>
> ovvero
>
> La bellezza non fa
> bollir la pentola.

Bisogna avere altre qualità oltre alla bellezza per sbarcare il lunario.

Con significato simile ho trovato altri due [proverbi](http://luirig.altervista.org/proverbi-ricerca/index.php?lemma=pentola):

> Il caldo dei lenzuoli non fa bollir la pentola.
>  L'amore non fa
> bollire la pentola.

Il significato nel testo da te citato è che un padre non affida la figlia ad un uomo che non può mantenerla adeguatamente.

Comment: Ma si tratta di un proverbio? Oppure è un'invenzione dell'autore?

Comment: Sembra un proverbio che ha significato simile ad una variante ligure che ho aggiunto alla risposta

Comment: Il legno verde è un legno assai giovane, acerbo; quindi può anche assumere credo il significato che il padre non vuole affidare ad uno sprovveduto senza esperienza.